# VERIZON rom on non VERIZON phone

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I own a galaxy s5 out of the USA, I want to install the new Galaxy S5 VERIZON Lineage 14.1 ROM on my phone, i am not sure what dows the VERIZON part means and if i can install the ROM on my phone, could anyone explain me that?

Comment: Verizon is a US carrier. What's the exact model number of your S5? Never install one that's not specifically made for it.